# pyqt4 and WebGL Earth JavaScript

Tags: html, pyqt4

When I try to display a html 2D earth map from google maps api with PyQt4 on python, it works, I can see the map and interact with.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

maphtml = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=drawing"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.5, -122.2),
          zoom: 10,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
          drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
          drawingControl: true,
          drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON]
          },
          polygonOptions: {editable: true, draggable: true},
        });
        drawingManager.setMap(map);

        var thePolygon = null;

        google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {
          if (thePolygon) 
            thePolygon.setMap(null);
          thePolygon = polygon;
          polygon.getPath().forEach(function (xy, i) {
            self.polygoncomplete(xy.lat(), xy.lng(), i);
          });
        });
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
'''

class Browser(QApplication):
    def __init__(self):
        QApplication.__init__(self, [])
        self.window = QWidget()
        self.window.setWindowTitle("Google Google Maps Maps");

        self.web = QWebView(self.window)
        self.web.setMinimumSize(800,800)
        self.web.page().mainFrame().addToJavaScriptWindowObject('self', self)
        self.web.setHtml(maphtml)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.window)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.web)

        self.window.show()
        self.exec_()

Browser()
```

But when to display a 3D map earth with WebGL Earth JavaScript, it doesn't work.I can only see text, but 3D earth can't be displayed. Any suggestion why? (I have got the same result with PyQt5 and the HTML script is working in my browser).

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

maphtml = '''

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://www.webglearth.com/v2/api.js"></script>
<script>
  function initialize() {
    var options = { zoom: 3.0, position: [47.19537,8.524404] };
    var earth = new WE.map('earth_div', options); 
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
  <h1>WebGL Earth API: Hello World</h1>
  <div id="earth_div" style="width:600px;height:400px;border:1px solid gray; padding:2px;"></div>
</body>
</html>

'''

class Browser(QApplication):
    def __init__(self):
        QApplication.__init__(self, [])
        self.window = QWidget()
        self.window.setWindowTitle("Google Google Maps Maps");

        self.web = QWebView(self.window)
        self.web.setMinimumSize(800,800)
        self.web.page().mainFrame().addToJavaScriptWindowObject('self', self)
        self.web.setHtml(maphtml)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.window)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.web)

        self.window.show()
        self.exec_()

Browser()
```

Comment: What is your version of pyqt?

Comment: I tried with the html that samples and I had the same problem, but when I try the following works correctly http://examples.webglearth.com/#helloworld

Comment: I use pyqt4 version 4.11.4

Comment: I have tried with your example but it still doesn't work

Comment: I have tested it in pyqt5 but I do not have the webkit module, I use QWebView from QtWebKitWidgets.

Comment: which version of PyQt5 do you use. I have tested with version 5.9 but I got the error [10552:11880:0820/203012.737:ERROR:gl_context_wgl.cc(78)] Could not share GL contexts.

Comment: pyqt5 5.9.1 on linux

Comment: it's working with version 5.8.2. But I don't have QWebView from QtWebKitWidgets. I had to use QWebEngineView from QtWebEngineWidgets. Could you share the code you used? thanks